# HammerJs Gesture with Angular 9

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, hammer.js, ionic5

I have a project with ionic/ anuglar 6 and hammerJs which rocks but I have decided to update to anuglar9.1.6 and ionic 5.0.0.

The problem is that my gesture doesn't work anymore ! my press and pressup are not recognized.

However I have imported HammerModule..

Please anyone can help me :/ .. I sure there is something to do

Thank you!

Please find below home.ts and home.html .

app.module:

```
imports: [HammerModule, BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    {
      provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG,
      useClass: IonicGestureConfig
  },
  ],
```

ionic-gesture.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class IonicGestureConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
    buildHammer(element: HTMLElement) {
        const mc = new (<any>window).Hammer(element);

        for (const eventName in this.overrides) {
            if (eventName) {
              mc.get(eventName).set(this.overrides[eventName]);
            }
          }

        return mc;
    }
}
```

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {

    public progress: number = 0;
    public pressState: string = "released";

    // Interval function
    protected interval: any;


    onPress($event) {
        console.log("onPress", $event);
        this.pressState = 'pressing';
        this.startInterval();
    }

    onPressUp($event) {
        console.log("onPressUp", $event);
        this.pressState = 'released';
        this.stopInterval();
    }

    startInterval() {
        const self = this;
        this.interval = setInterval(function () {
            self.progress = self.progress + 1;
        }, 50);
    }

    stopInterval() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }


}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>
          Long Press Demo
      </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2> Button Progress: {{ progress }}</h2>
  <h2> Presses State: {{ pressState }}</h2>
  <ion-button (press)="onPress($event)" (pressup)="onPressUp($event)">Press Me</ion-button>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: just curious: why did you decide to use Hammer and not Ionic built in gestures ?

Comment: I want to implement x and y swipe but ionic gesture is cool for custom gesture.
I'm wrong ?
By the wait, if you have an idea for x and y swipe with ionic-gesture. I already have x swipe

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be related to the fact that hammerjs script itself is no longer bundled with Angular since v6.x.

See here: https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/HammerModule

> Note that applications still need to include the HammerJS script
> itself. This module simply sets up the coordination layer between
> HammerJS and Angular's EventManager.

Try to import hammerjs inside your main.ts and see if this helps to resolve the issue?

```
npm install hammerjs --save
```

then inside polyfill.ts or main.ts:

```
import "hammerjs";
```

Comment: oh;) bummer. BTW do you have window['Hammer'] in the context of your app? does it initialize properly? this way you could eliminate whats wrong

Comment: I don't understand, so I don't think so: Can you explain me ?

Comment: so after your app loaded hit up console and check window object to feature Hammer. Just type window.Hammer

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see where I have to type window.Hammer...

Comment: use google chrome in dev mode - the console after you do my serve

Comment: Please see the answer : 
window.Hammer
ƒ Hammer(element, options) {
    options = options || {};
    options.recognizers = ifUndefined(options.recognizers, Hammer.defaults.preset);
    return new Manager(element, options);
}

Comment: good that means Hammer script is loaded. Can you try to remove temporarily your overrides for hammer config sand see if hammer works without custom config?

Comment: Hammer(element, options) {
    options = options || {};
    options.recognizers = ifUndefined(options.recognizers, Hammer.defaults.preset);
    return new Manager(element, options);
}

The same answer as before

Comment: I did not mean to check if script is loaded again (we already know that), I asked you if you could remove custom hammer config and test the (press) event in the app, can you do that?

Comment: This is my  project : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-m8xt8c?file=package.json 
And the same projec does't work in local with chrome and firefox...